# javacc token regular expressions and_symbol_in 

Tags: regex, javacc

I need to describe the token containing some word. The word could contain english letters and some other special symbols, but shouldn`t begin with some defined english letters (for example, 'O").

It looks like I need AND_SYMBOL_IN operation or something, but I haven`t find it in the javacc documentation.
I need the behavior something like this:

```
TOKEN : { < LETTERS: (
  (~["O", "-"] AND_SYMBOL_IN ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","-",".","&","|","0"-"9"])? (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","-",".","&","|","0"-"9"])+
  ) > }
```

I can create special token(like below), but I believe there is more nice decision, isn`t it?

```
TOKEN : { < #LETTEREX: (
["a"-"z","A"-"N","P"-"Z",".","&","|","0"-"9","-"]) > }

TOKEN : { < LETTERS: (
(< LETTEREX > ) (< LETTEREX > | ["O"])+
) > }
```

Comment: The internet doesn't seem to have a document describing `AND_SYMBOL_IN`, so without personal knowledge of JavaCC we cannot help you.

Comment: I doubt there be a 'nicer' (ie. more concise) solution - what you want amounts to iterated regexp matching in token recognition. i don't believe anyone has gone to the hassle of implementing that feature generically for a lexer generator. it might be desirable for some peculiar needs in unicode context but for your task i'd suggest to cling to your solution. another option might be to set  TOKEN_FACTORY and tweak `newToken` into returning different tokens when matching a 'word' - see the javacc docs. hope that helps, regards

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC resolves ambiguities between equally sized matches using the order that the matching tokens are declared in the grammar. So one possibility is to match the token you don't want before the token you do:

For example:

```
TOKEN : { < #LETTER : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","-",".","&","|","0"-"9"] > }
TOKEN : { < WORDS_STARTING_WITH_O : "O" ( < LETTER > )+ > }
TOKEN : { < WORDS_NOT_STARTING_WITH_O : (< LETTER > )+ > }
```

How suitable this is depends on how many special cases you have and how complicated they are.